# This batch script returns incorrect value when invoked from a different directory

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, directory

This batch script returns incorrect value when invoked from a different directory.  I am hoping someone can help me fix this so that it always determines the correct  APP_HOME directory.

The script is located in a position like:

```
C:\Temp\MyApplication\bin\runner.bat
```

And, I want to execute it from:

```
C:\Temp\OutsideDir\runApp.bat
```

When I try this, I get 'OutsideDir' but I want it to get 'bin' :

```
C:\Temp\OutsideDir>C:\Temp\MyApplication\bin\runner.bat
Current directory is: C:\Temp\MyApplication\bin
This folder name: OutsideDir
Function arg must match actual folder name.
This script may not be running from the expected folder.
There was an error.
```

And here is the script:

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

TITLE Script %~n0%~x0 running from %~dp0

CALL :getparentfolder bin

ECHO My app home is: %APP_HOME%

GOTO :END

:: function to get parent folder name or APP_HOME of scripts currrent folder
:: function requires current folders name as an arg or it will fail to run
:getparentfolder dirName
SET "BIN_HOME=%~dp0"
IF "%BIN_HOME:~-1%"=="\" SET "BIN_HOME=%BIN_HOME:~0,-1%"
ECHO Current directory is: %BIN_HOME%
FOR /F "tokens=1,* delims=^\" %%I IN ("%BIN_HOME%") DO (
  SET THISFOLDER=%%~nxI
)
ECHO This folder name: %THISFOLDER%
IF "%~1"=="%THISFOLDER%" (
  SET APP_HOME=!BIN_HOME:\%THISFOLDER%=!
  ECHO APP_HOME: %APP_HOME%
) ELSE (
  ECHO Function arg must match actual expected folder name.
  ECHO This script may not be running from the expected folder.
  GOTO :ERROR
)
EXIT /B 0

:ERROR
ECHO There was an error.
PING.exe -n 10 -w 1 127.0.0.1>nul
:END
PING.exe -n 10 -w 1 127.0.0.1>nul
ECHO The script %~n0%~x0 is finished.
```

Comment: Have you tried `CD C:\Temp\OutsideDir\` before running your bat?

Comment: I want the script to return information about ITSELF only and not information about the script location from where it was invoked.  This is because I want to call this script from other scripts.  It is hard to explain but I hope that is enough.  This script must be able to determine its OWN home regardless of the script that called it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
@echo off&setlocal
SET "BIN_HOME=%~dp0"
IF "%BIN_HOME:~-1%"=="\" SET "BIN_HOME=%BIN_HOME:~0,-1%"
ECHO Current directory is: %BIN_HOME%
FOR %%I IN ("%BIN_HOME%") DO (
  SET THISFOLDER=%%~nxI
)
ECHO This folder name: %THISFOLDER%
```

output is:

```
C:\TEMP\OutsideDir>C:\Temp\MyApplication\bin\runner.bat
Current directory is: C:\TEMP\MyApplication\bin
This folder name: bin
```

Comment: Yep, you nailed it.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The scripts own home directory is %~dp0.

Your code is getting the name of the current working directory, hence it's failing because it doesn't match the argument you supply (bin).

> SET "BIN_HOME=%~dp0"

Sets BIN_HOME to the path of the directory containing the script (in your case c:\temp\myapplication\bin)

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,* delims=^\" %%I IN ("%BIN_HOME%") DO (
   SET THISFOLDER=%%~nxI
)
```

Extracts tokens from the BIN_HOME variable using \ as a delimiter.  You have specified you want a maximum of two tokens (tokens=1,*), so these will be allocated to the variables %%I and %%J as follows (assuming %BIN_HOME% is c:\temp\myapplication\bin:

```
%%I = C:   (everything up to the first backslash)
%%J = temp\myapplication\bin (the remainder of the string
```

Then attempts to get the file name part of th value %%I (%%~nxI).  This gets the name of the current working directory (the path "C:" refers to the current working directory).

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve, why can't you simply do something like:

```
SET APP_HOME=%~dp0
```

**UPDATE**

> I can't do that because %~dp0 refers to the current directory and not the parent of the current directory

If you want the parent of the script's directory, you can do it with something like:

```
SET MYDIR=%~dp0
echo My directory is %MYDIR%

CALL :GETPARENT PARENT "%MYDIR:~0,-1"

echo Parent is %PARENT%

GOTO :EOF

:GETPARENT
SET %1=%~dp2
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: I can't do that because %~dp0 refers to the current directory and not the parent of the current directory.  What I am really trying to retrieve is the grandparent dir of the current dir of runner.bat as opposed to the runApp.bat grandparent dir .

Comment: @djangofan, I'm not really clear about what you want. You say you want the "grandparent" directory, but the answer you accepted doesn't do this.

Comment: thanks for yout help. it does. I posted on my blog with the answer: http://thegreenoak.blogspot.com/2013/05/an-improved-testrunnerbat-for-soapui-on.html

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,* delims=\" %%I IN ("%BIN_HOME%") DO (
  SET THISFOLDER=%%~nxJ
)
SET thisfolder

FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ("%BIN_HOME%") DO (
  IF /i "%%~nxI"=="%~1" (SET APP_HOME=%%~dpI) ELSE (SET APP_HOME=)
)
IF NOT DEFINED app_home GOTO error
SET app_home=%app_home:~0,-1%
SET app
```

The caret is not required. Note %%~nx`J`

Personally, I'd employ the second substitute method...

and setting your title is easier done with `Script %~nx0 ...`